# Combine SQL Data into 1 row

Tags: sql, duplicates

I'm attempting to build code to create an SSRS report. The folder type ID 19 indicates a Member ID. If the Folder type ID includes a *1300 it indicates a provider ID that is located in that field, prior to the *1300. The issue with how I am currently doing it is that it is creating 2 rows. One where the Provider ID is populated but the Member ID is showing as NULL. The other where the Member ID is populated but the Provider ID is showing as NULL. What I want to do is combine them so I'm only returning 1 row, with both the Member ID and the Provider ID populated correctly. What is the best way to go about this? Thanks in advance for any assistance!

```
SELECT
xfl.xml_file_id                         
, dh.document_id                            
, dh.document_description                   
, dh.document_date                          
, CASE WHEN xfi.FOLDER_TYPE_ID = '19' THEN xfi.folder_id ELSE null END AS 
MemberID
, CASE WHEN RIGHT(xfi.folder_id, 5) = '*1300' THEN LEFT(xfi.folder_id, 
LEN(xfi.folder_id) - 5) ELSE null END AS ProviderID
, xfl.xml_file_name                         
, dp.document_file_path                     


FROM 
reporting.[FacetsRunout].[XML_FILE_LIST]            xfl 
JOIN reporting.[FacetsRunout].[Folder_ID]           xfi      
ON xfi.XML_FILE_ID = XFL.XML_FILE_ID
JOIN reporting.[FacetsRunout].[Document_Page]       dp       
ON dp.XML_FILE_ID = xfl.XML_FILE_ID
JOIN reporting.[FacetsRunout].[Document_Header]     dh       
ON 
   dh.XML_FILE_ID = xfl.XML_FILE_ID

WHERE
dh.DOCUMENT_ID = '07330C906700'
```

Comment: I think you can try `group by` and use `max()` on the columns you want

Comment: SQL is just a language used my multiple dbms vendors.  Which dbms is this?

Comment: On a side note: The data model looks weird to me. A document has a header and pages. I'd expect a document ID to link the two tables. Instead there is an XML file ID. So the document is an XML file? Why then the extra XML file table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by all the columns that you select and aggregate on the columns that you want to combine into 1 row:

```
SELECT
xfl.xml_file_id                         
, dh.document_id                            
, dh.document_description                   
, dh.document_date                          
, MAX(CASE WHEN xfi.FOLDER_TYPE_ID = '19' THEN xfi.folder_id END) AS MemberID
, MAX(CASE WHEN RIGHT(xfi.folder_id, 5) = '*1300' THEN LEFT(xfi.folder_id,LEN(xfi.folder_id) - 5) END) AS ProviderID
, xfl.xml_file_name                         
, dp.document_file_path                     
FROM 
reporting.[FacetsRunout].[XML_FILE_LIST]            xfl 
JOIN reporting.[FacetsRunout].[Folder_ID]           xfi      
ON xfi.XML_FILE_ID = XFL.XML_FILE_ID
JOIN reporting.[FacetsRunout].[Document_Page]       dp       
ON dp.XML_FILE_ID = xfl.XML_FILE_ID
JOIN reporting.[FacetsRunout].[Document_Header]     dh       
ON dh.XML_FILE_ID = xfl.XML_FILE_ID
WHERE dh.DOCUMENT_ID = '07330C906700'
GROUP BY 
xfl.xml_file_id                         
, dh.document_id                            
, dh.document_description                   
, dh.document_date                          
, xfl.xml_file_name                         
, dp.document_file_path
```

I also removed `ELSE null` from both CASE statements because it is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the two attributes in subqueires in the select clause:

```
SELECT
  dh.xml_file_id,
  dh.document_id,
  dh.document_description,
  dh.document_date,
  (
    SELECT xfi.folder_id
    FROM reporting.facetsrunout.folder_id xfi
    WHERE xfi.xml_file_id = dh.xml_file_id
    AND xfi.folder_type_id = '19'
  ) AS memberid,
  (
    SELECT LEFT(xfi.folder_id, LEN(xfi.folder_id) - 5)
    FROM reporting.facetsrunout.folder_id xfi
    WHERE xfi.xml_file_id = dh.xml_file_id
    AND RIGHT(xfi.folder_id, 5) = '*1300'
  ) AS providerid,
  xfl.xml_file_name
  dp.document_file_path
FROM reporting.facetsrunout.document_header dh
JOIN reporting.facetsrunout.document_page dp ON dp.xml_file_id = dh.xml_file_id
JOIN reporting.facetsrunout.xml_file_list xfl ON xfl.xml_file_id = dh.xml_file_id
WHERE dh.document_id = '07330C906700';
```